# Cómo puedo quitar los tildes a los char de un arreglo?

Tags: c, array, ascii

Cuando tengo el arreglo, entro a un `for` para ver individualmente cada `char` y cuando hago un `print` de estos datos, los `char` que tienen tildes me los considera como dos valores.En `ASCII`, el tilde es 195 y luego le sigue el `ASCII` de la letra, por ejemplo:

```
oído  -> o = 111, tilde = 195, i=173, d=100, o=111
```

**`Quiero saber como puedo quitar el tilde del arreglo o como puedo convertir la`i`con tilde en una`i`sin tilde.`**

Comment: Solo queres remplazar la I o todos los tildes?

Answer (score 1):

Se puede ver que los dos números (tilde = 195  e  i = 173) que has mostrado no coinciden para nada con los caracteres ascii del acento y la i. Sin embargo si pasamos estos dos números a hexadecimal y los juntamos para hacer un Word (16 bits) obtenemos el número **0xC3AD** (0xC3=195 y 0xAD=173) que pasado a decimal es el 50093. Curiosamente este número nos da el carácter de admiración **¡** bastante parecido a la **í**. Dado que no es un código de 16 bits solo nos queda la opción de una codificación en 2 bytes. Esto lo podemos comprobar pulsando **Alt+50093**. El carácter obtenido es la admiración **¡**.

En la “Table B-2 Unicode Character Code Ranges for UTF-8 Character Codes” se puede ver que los caracteres ASCII solo utilizan un byte (0x00-0x7F) mientras que los caracteres para
Europa (excepto ASCII), árabe y hebreo, utilizan dos bytes. El primer byte puede estar entre los valores 0xC2 (194) y 0xDF (223). El segundo byte puede estar entre 0x80 y 0xBF (128 y 191).

Se ve que tus números coinciden en este marco de codificación y en http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ podemos ver que la 'i' es **0xc3 0xad**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Viendo esto yo utilizaría un if que comprobase si el byte leído es igual a 0xC3 (195) puesto que eso implicaría que detrás viene otro carácter. Luego habría que convertir el siguiente carácter pero como no puedes utilizar cambios directos de bits (como en el caso de las mayúsculas y minúsculas en ASCII) podrías utilizar un ***case*** o una secuencia ***if*** para detectar las vocales y cambiarlas.

Te dejo los valores ASCII y UTF-8 de las vocales.

```
ASCII       UTF-8 (Segundo Byte)
a – 0x61        á – 0xA1
e – 0x65        é – 0xA9
i – 0x69        í – 0xAD
o – 0x6F        ó – 0XB3
u – 0x75        ú – 0xBA
```

Código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(v_ascii); i++)  {
    if (v_ascii[i]==0xC3) {
        //Aquí el código de detección y cambio de vocal.
        //El cambio ha de hacerse sobre el siguiente carácter, v_ascii[i+1]
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 por el análisis sobre la codificación, en realidad se trata de UTF-8.

Comment: Perdonad mi ignorancia pero para qué sirven los comentarios. No entiendo el comentario a mi respuesta. Quiero decir, yo no he hablado de otra cosa que no sea UTF-8.¿por qué dices -en realidad se trata de UTF-8?. Disculpad pero soy nuevo por aquí y aún me queda mucho por aprender.

Comment: Los comentarios son para cualquier cosa que no sean directamente preguntas y respuestas. Por acá, un comentario que comienza con _"+1"_ significa algo como _"voté a favor de tu pregunta/respuesta"_ y una explicación del por qué dí mi voto a favor. Un comentario que comienza con _"-1"_, por el contrario, significa _"voté en contra"_, seguido de la explicación del por qué. No es necesario dejar comentarios cada vez que se vota. Yo lo he hecho porque no _respondes_ directamente la pregunta específica del AP, pero apuntas en la dirección correcta de su problema y le das una solución.

Comment: Ok, gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Y gracias por el +1

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes notar que realmente el código ascii de la **i** con acento(**í**) es el 161 minúscula y 214 para la mayúscula , y la **i** sin acento es el 105 para la minúscula y 73 para la mayúscula.

Un ejemplo a esto es:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 14 //Puedes utilizar strlen de string.h

int main()
{
    char buffer[] = "Íbamos íbamos";

    printf("texto antes de procesar: %s\n", buffer);    
    for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
    {
        const char *caracter = &buffer[i];        
        char iConAcento = 161;
        char IConAcento = 214;
        if(*caracter == iConAcento)
            buffer[i] = 105;
        else if(*caracter == IConAcento)
            buffer[i] = 73;
    }

    printf("texto despues de procesar: %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Ese código debería servir, pero a mi no funciono, porque mi sistema trabaja bajo la codificación de caracteres *Unicode UTF-8*, ademas depende también mucho del compilador.

Un ejemplo más genérico, pero ni tanto porque también depende del sistema y el compilador es:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LEN 14 //Puedes utilizar strlen de string.h

int main()
{
    char buffer[] = "Íbamos íbamos";

    printf("texto antes de procesar: %s\n", buffer);    
    for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
    {
        const char *caracter = &buffer[i];        
        char iConAcento = 'í';
        char IConAcento = 'Í';
        if(*caracter == iConAcento)
            buffer[i] = 'i';
        else if(*caracter == IConAcento)
            buffer[i] = 'I';
    }

    printf("texto despues de procesar: %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

En este segundo ejemplo, ya me funciona, pero el compilador se me queja con el siguiente aviso:  `constante de carácter con múltiples caracteres`, te remito a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149757/como-corrijo-el-error-warning-multi-character-character-constant-wmultichar), donde se explica muy bien de que se trata.

Answer (score -1):

recomiendo que dentro del for, el **print** lo metas en un **if**:

```
if ( arreglo[i] != 195 ) {
    print arreglo[i]
}
```

Comment: Deberías poner una solución legal en el lenguaje C... ese `print` lo mismo es válido en python pero en C las funciones no se invocan así. Eso sin contar con que la función `print` no existe (quizás en alguna librería de terceros, pero en tal caso deberías indicar dicha dependencia). Si no corriges la respuesta corres el riesgo de empezar a recibir negativos