# Me aparece [Error] expected unqualified-id before '\x72677629'

Tags: c++

Éste es el código:

```
/* Programa 01
creado por: Julio Cesar Rodriguez Cardenas
MMXVI*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

'int main (int argc, char** argv)':
 {
    char  algoritmo;
    string nombre   =   0;
    double libras   =   0;
    double pies =   0;
    double kg   =   0;
    double metros   =   0;
    int voto    =   1;
    int* cand   =   NULL;
    string mayor    =   0;
    int i   =   0;
    int g   =   0;
    int total   =   0;
    int porc    =   0;
    int llamadasr   =   0;
    int min =   0;
    double tarea    =   0;
    double totaltotal   =   0;
    double pllamada =   0;
    int area    =   0;
    double t12  =   0;
    int ll12    =   0;
    double t15  =   0;
    int ll15    =   0;
    double t18  =   0;
    int ll18    =   0;
    double t19  =   0;
    int ll19    =   0;
    double t23  =   0;
    int ll23    =   0;
    double t25  =   0;
    int ll25    =   0;
    double t29  =   0;
    int ll29    =   0;
    cout<<"producto integrador unidad II."<<endl;
    cout<<"dame una opcion, para saber que algoritmo resolver:";
    cin>>algoritmo;
    switch (algoritmo)
     {
        case 1:
            cout<<"El algoritmo oso";
            cout<<"¿Cuál es el nombre del oso polar?";
            cin >>nombre;
            cout<<"¿Cuántas libras pesa el oso polar?";
            cin >>libras;
            cout<<"¿Cuántos pies mide el oso polar?";
            cin>>pies;
            kg = libras*0.454;
            metros = pies*0.348;
            cout<<"el oso"<<nombre<<"tiene un peso de"<<kg<<"kiogramos y mide"<<metros<<"metros."<<endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"El algortimo de los votos";
            switch (voto = !0)
            {
            cout<<"¿cual es tu voto?";
            cin>>voto;
            for ("voto";) {
                case 1:;
                        cand[1]+1;
                        break;
                case 2:;
                        cand[2]+1;
                        break;
                case 3:;
                        cand[3]+1;
                        break;
                case 4:;
                        cand[4]+1;
                        break;
                case 5:;
                        cand[5]+1;
                        break;
                case 6:;
                        cand[6]+1;
                        break;
            };
                default:
                    cout<<"Opcion no valida."<<endl;
                break;
            break;
            for (i=1; i<6; i++){
            total   =   total+cand[i];
            (cand[i] =  mayor);
            mayor   =   cand[i];
            g   =   i;
            break;
        }
            porc    =   mayor*100/total;
            cout<<"hubo"<<total<<"votos";
            for (i=1; i<=6; i++) {
                cout<<"el candidato"<<i<<"obtuvo"<<cand[i]<<"votos";
                break;
            cout<<"el ganador fue el candidato"<<g<<"con un porcentaje de"<<porc<<"porciento del total";
        }
        case 7 : "el algoritmo de las llamadas";
                cout<<"algoritmo de llamadas";
                cout<<"¿cuantas llamadas se hicieron?";
                cin>>llamadasr;
                for (i=1; i<=llamadasr; i++){
                    cout<<"¿cuantos minutos duro la llamada?";
                    cin>>min;
                    cout<<"¿a que area se hicieron las llamadas?";
                    cin>>area;
                    switch (area){
                    case 1:
                        pllamada    =   min*2.20;
                        t12 =   pllamada+t12;
                        totaltotal  =   t12+totaltotal;
                        ll12    =   ll12+1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pllamada    =   min*2.80;
                        t15 =   pllamada+t15;
                        totaltotal  =   t15+totaltotal;
                        ll15    =   ll15+1;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pllamada    =   min*4.75;
                        t18 =   pllamada+t18;
                        totaltotal  =   t18+totaltotal;
                        ll18    =   ll18+1;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pllamada    =   min*3.65;
                        t19 =   pllamada+t19;
                        totaltotal  =   t19+totaltotal;
                        ll19    =   ll19+1;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        pllamada    =   min*6.25;
                        t23 =   pllamada+t23;
                        totaltotal  =   t12+totaltotal;
                        ll23    =   ll23+1;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        pllamada    =   min*6.25;
                        t25 =   pllamada+t25;
                        totaltotal  =   t25+totaltotal;
                        ll25    =   ll25+1;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        pllamada    =   min*5.15;
                        t29 =   pllamada+t29;
                        totaltotal  =   t29+totaltotal;
                        ll29    =   ll29+1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        cout<<"Opcion no valida";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                cout<<"se realizaron"<<llamadasr<<"llamadas";
                cout<<ll12<<"llamadas al area 12 para un total de"<<t12<<"pesos";
                cout<<ll15<<"llamadas al area 12 para un total de"<<t15<<"pesos";
                cout<<ll18<<"llamadas al area 12 para un total de"<<t18<<"pesos";
                cout<<ll19<<"llamadas al area 12 para un total de"<<t19<<"pesos";
                cout<<ll23<<"llamadas al area 12 para un total de"<<t23<<"pesos";
                cout<<ll25<<"llamadas al area 12 para un total de"<<t25<<"pesos";
                cout<<ll29<<"llamadas al area 12 para un total de"<<t29<<"pesos";
                cout<<"para todas las llamadas fueron"<<totaltotal<<"pesos";
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout <<"Opcion invalida"<<endl;     
    }

    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;   
    }
```

Comment: Tienes varios errores de sintaxis (entre otros). Cambia `'int main (int argc, char** argv)':` por `int main (int argc, char** argv)` (sin las comillas simples y los dos puntos del final) y ese error se irá, pero te aparecerán muchos otros. Por ejemplo, cambia el `for ("voto";) {` por `switch (voto) {`, asignaciones de cadena incorrectos, etc.. pero ya tienes un punto de comienzo.

Comment: Esto que has pegado ni siquiera compila, es demasiado código para el problema que tienes. Tu problema es un identificador en una línea y carácter concreto ¿dónde te marca el compilador el error?

Answer (score 5):

Todo tu error se puede reducir a estas líneas:

```
'int main (int argc, char** argv)':
{
}
```

Esto [produce el siguiente error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Aqg03QPukaUpJQ7z):

> ```
> prog.cc:1:1: warning: character constant too long for its type
> 'int main (int argc, char** argv)':
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> prog.cc:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '\x72677629'
> ```

No se en qué lenguaje crees que estás programando, pero no es [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

---

En C++, unos caracteres encerrados entre comillas simples son [un literal multicaracter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/149784/2742), su soporte es condicional (los compiladores pueden decidir no darle soporte) y su interpretación depende de la implementación (cada compilador puede decidir interpretarlo a su manera).

Acompañas al literal multicaracter con dos puntos (`:`), lo que crea una [etiqueta](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Labels), que puede usarse en una instrucción `goto` o `switch`, pero el literal que usas como etiqueta no es reconocido como tal, de ahí el error. Quita las comillas y los dos puntos:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    // código...
}
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Estás programando (presuntamente) en C++, por lo que no deberías usar inclusiones de C, en lugar de `<math.h>` deberías usar `<cmath>` lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48305/2742) para saber por qué.
- En C++ se aconseja que las variables tengan el ámbito más pequeño posible, uno de los motivos es que es más fácil razonar sobre la utilidad de las variables si están más cerca del punto en que se usan. Lo mismo sucede con la cláusula `using namespace std;`.
- Si no estás usando los parámetros de `main`, no los definas.
- No abuses de `std::end`, lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/2742) para saber por qué.
- Deja respirar a tus variables, en los 90 teníamos pantallas de 80 caracteres de ancho y 25 líneas de alto (no había más remedio que compactar el código), pero hace décadas que no tenemos esas limitaciones, pon unos espacios en el código: hará que sea más fácil de leer y tu yo del futuro te lo agradecerá.
- Sigue el [principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica) encapsulando tareas no relacionadas con `main` en funciones individuales.
- Los nombres de tus variables son confusos, cuesta determinar su objetivo al leer su nombre, evita usar acrónimos, siglas, abreviaturas y variables cuyo nombre sea una sola letra.
- Inicializas un `std::string` con un valor cero (`0`) lo cuál lanza una excepción de tipo `'std::logic_error'`, inicializa con cadena vacía (`""`) o no uses inicializador (confía en el constructor por defecto).
- El primer `switch` del *algortimo* de los votos contiene código fuera de etiqueta.
- La instrucción `for ("voto";)` es un disparate, la instrucción `(cand[i] = mayor);` no requiere paréntesis.
- El puntero `cand` lo usas sin asignarle memoria, eso provocará que tu programa falle en tiempo de ejecución.
- Usa objetos para agrupar información relacionada en lugar de crear un ejercito de variables con ninguna relación aparente entre si.

Tu código es una pesadilla.