# ¿Como declarar una variable tipo carácter y asignarle una palabra?

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que contiene varios menús con varias opciones en donde quisiera que cuando el usuario elija una opción se guarde el nombre de la opción que eligió, la abreviación de la misma para que a futuro se haga mas fácil usar el método de inserción para ordenar con la siglas y por ultimo que vaya contando las veces que se elija ese producto, es decir, cuando elija la opción se guarden esas tres cosas y no estar colocando cout cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
char NP, CS, S, E, SG;
int main()
{
    int op1, i, LD1 = 0, LE1 = 0, YG1 = 0, HE1 = 0;
    cout << "seleccione su producto favorito" << endl;
    cout << "1-LD (Leche Descremada)" << endl;
    cout << "2-LE (Leche Entera)" << endl;
    cout << "3-YG (Yogurt)" << endl;
    cout << "4-HE (Helados)" << endl;
    cin >> op1;
    switch (op1) {
    case 1:
        cout << "Leche Descremada" << endl;
        SG;
        cout << "LD" << endl;
        LD1++;
        cout << LD1 << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        NP;
        cout << "Leche Entera" << endl;
        SG;
        cout << "LE" << endl;
        LE1++;
        break;
    case 3:
        NP;
        cout << "Yogurt" << endl;
        SG;
        cout << "YG" << endl;
        YG1++;
        break;
    case 4:
        NP;
        cout << "Helados" << endl;
        SG;
        cout << "HE" << endl;
        HE1++;
        break;
    case 5:
        return 0;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "las opciones son de 1-4" << endl;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He releído la pregunta 3 veces, y aún no se cual es tu problema **concreto**. ¿ Que error tienes ? ¿ De compilación, de ejecución ? Deberías proporcionar un [mcve].

Comment: disculpe si no soy muy especifico, lo que intento saber es que si es posible declarar una variable tipo carácter y asignarle una palabra (es el equivalente a esto int x=6 pero en carácter), porque lo que busco es que el usuario me elija una opción y con esa opción que me guarde,muestre y cuente

Comment: `chart miCaracter = 'A'` las comillas simple son para caracteres y no puede haber mas de uno,

Comment: @Samir puede haber más de uno, pero [será un entero (`int`)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/149784/2742).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso seria conveniente que pongas el carácter de la siguiente manera 'A', de igual forma tengo entendido que el char solo admite una letra o caracter.

Tambien veo que en la linea `cout << LD1 << endl;` haría falta poner `"LD1".`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda