# character constant too long for its type

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente error en eclipse programando en c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {    cout << "Ingrese el numero: "; //Aqui es donde me marca el error 
return 0; }
```

He estado buscando y comparando programas y todo esta bien o eso creo si alguien me ayuda a solucionarlo

Comment: ¿Exactamente que hace tu programa?, Y te prodría ayudar mejor si mandas un poco mas de código hacia arriba y abajo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el error que te marca? asi como esta, la pregunta va a terminar cerrada porque es poco clara...

Answer (score -1):

El código que muestras no contiene ningún error. Sin embargo, si el código fuese este:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {    cout << 'Ingrese el numero: '; //Aqui es donde me marca el error 
return 0; }
```

Tendrías la siguiente alarma (que no error):

> ```
> warning: character constant too long for its type
>             int main() {  cout << 'Ingrese el numero: '; //Aqui es donde me marca el error
>                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

La diferencia es usar comillas simples (`'`) en lugar de comillas dobles (`"`). Y el motivo es que es un [literal multicarácter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/149757/2742) con demasiados caracteres.